# What does saying IKEA like this indicating?

Tags: dialogue, friends

In the TV-show Friends there's the following scene in Season 3 Episode 23:

> [Scene: Pete's apartment, Monica showing the gang around.]
>
> Monica: Okay, this is the den.
>
> Chandler: (sitting down on the couch) I-kea! This is comfortable.

It is obvious that he relates Ikea company to the situation.

My question here, when sat there he first said "I" then completed it with "kea" as if "I" indicates an exclamation of extreme comfort. What is he indicating?

Comment: I think you pretty much answered your own question.

Comment: I think that is the case when IKEA is really comfortable. But I heard many times that Americans consider IKEA as a low quality production, so how come?

Comment: Low quality does not necessarily mean uncomfortable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chandler's comment seems to be a corruption of the Spanish phrase "***[¡Ay, caramba!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A1Ay,_caramba!)***". The joke is obviously that his expression (of surprise at the comfort of the sofa) **also combines the name of a popular furniture manufacturer.**

I guess the joke would have worked the same way (albeit less funny, I'll grudgingly admit) if he'd tried on a comfortable suit and said "*Ah-mani...!*"

Comment: Ay Caramba is a bit of a nonsense phrases (it was popularised by someone called Caramba as their catchphrase) but the general tone is more like "Oh my word!", at least as used in popular media like the Simpsons...